# What folder to place Large Video files?

Tags: uploads, videos

I'm using WordPress to upload videos. I have to use WordPress to upload the videos, because they need to remain past a password protected side of the website.

I have access to the WordPress content folders, so I can move media in and out from the folders, and it would be reflective on the WordPress (basically FTP).

Currently, my upload limit is 200MB, and I'm having trouble uploading anything past about 30MBs. I'm getting an HTTP error.
I have the larger video files now sitting in `wp-content/.../2017/08` where all my other uploads are, and the videos are not populating into WordPress Dashboard area.

Any ideas on how to get this successfully into WordPress?

Comment: The media library doesn't list files in the uploads folder, it lists posts of type `attachment` in the database that are created on uploads. Otherwise large media libraries would be super slow with costly folder scans on every page load. As an aside, an unlisted youtube video will be just as secure as uplaading the video since anybody with the URL can download/watch the file

Comment: In order to have the videos listed in the Media Manager, you need to upload them from there, not by FTP.

Answer (score 0):

WordPress doesn't process uploaded files directly from file system, it stores information about them as attachments in database.

If you need to turn a directly uploaded file into an attachment the term for it would be a *sideload*. There are some API functions in WP to help with the task, starting with `media_handle_sideload()`.

Also note that *none* of WordPress is designed to function from private location on web server. Uploads folder is typically public, as is everything in it (knowing URLs to files).